# How to loop multiple passed parameters in Google closure template?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-templates

Lets say i have this arrays in JS:

```
var array1[];
var array2[];
var array3[];
```

And those arrays have some values, and I want to pass them to google's closure template. Lets say my closure template's file name is MyArraysTemplate, and I want to target inside the MyArraysTemplate this specific template --> "ThisArrayTemplate"  Like this:

```
var myhtml = MyArraysTemplate.ThisArrayTemplate({
   array1 = array1,
   array2 = array2,
   array3 = array3
});
```

Now how do i loop on all of those arrays with just one loop cause I want to put them in one table. Something like this:

```
{ foreach $array_1 in $array1 $array_2 in $array2 $array_3 in $array3 }

#Build their table here

{/foreach}
```

How to do it? That code above is invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Define a template `table` that takes one array as parameter, then in the main template call it three times:

```
{call .table}
  {param array: $array1 /}
{/call}
{call .table}
  {param array: $array2 /}
{/call}
{call .table}
  {param array: $array3 /}
{/call}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var array1[];
var array2[];
var array3[];
var arrSending = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array.push(arrSending,array1[i];
}
for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
    array.push(arrSending,array2[i];
}
for (var i = 0; i < array3.length; i++) {
    array.push(arrSending,array3[i];
}
```

Now you have a single array `arrSending` that contains the combined array values.

Comment: And how do I access each element inside the array in the closure template?

Comment: I suppose you'd have to keep track of the count (length) of each of the original arrays and make sure you split `arrSending` before processing it through the closures.